# Add html elements with Javascript using loop

Tags: javascript

Through an `object`, I need to create HTML elements using the `Javascript loop`.

The sample code displays the contract, contract lots and batch invoices.

Well, I just need to display the contracts as a list and, for each contract, add the `lots` of the contract in a drop-down list (selection option)` and then display the invoices in another list, according to the selected lot.

`there was a problem displaying batches, but Barmar's comment helped me`

**Resume**:
1: Create an event to load invoices when changing the batch

2: load the lots and invoices related to the contract by clicking on the contract.

**Sample code**

**UPDATE**: Added loading invoices

```html
<div id="div-contracts"></div>
<ul id="div-invoices"></ul>
<style>
#div-contracts {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
.loren {
    float:left;
    width: 45px;
}
.ipsulum {
    float:left;
    width: 35%;
}
</style>


<script>
let object = {
    name: 'wagner',
    contracts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            contract: '123',
            batches: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    batch: '1',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/01/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/02/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    batch: '2',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/04/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/05/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            contract: '456',
            batches: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    batch: '1',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 15,
                            due: '01/01/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 14,
                            due: '01/02/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
};

let getById = (id, parent) => parent ? parent.getElementById(id) : getById(id, document);
const DOM =  {
    contract: getById('div-contracts'),
};

function htmlForBatchsOptions(contract) {
    return contract.batches.map(batch => `<option value="${batch.id}">${batch.batch}</option>`).join('');
};

function htmlForInvoices(invoices) {
    let invoiceLi = '';
    for (const invoice of invoices) {
        invoiceLi += `<li>${invoice.value} - ${invoice.due}</li>`;
    }
    return document.querySelector('#div-invoices').innerHTML = invoiceLi;
};

for (const contract of object.contracts) {
    DOM.contract.innerHTML +=
    `<div class="contract">
        <div class="loren">
            <span>${contract.contract}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ipsulum">
            <select class="sel-batch">
                ${htmlForBatchsOptions(contract)}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    
    let = contractInAttendance = 1;
    let batchFilteredByContractId = contract.batches.filter(batch => batch.id === contractInAttendance);
    
    htmlForInvoices(batchFilteredByContractId[0].invoices);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Change `let batchOptions;` to `let batchOptions = "";`

Comment: ok, it works and I don't see any more undefined. have a simpler chance of getting the same result, I mean the code in general?

Comment: You can use: `batchOptions = contract.batches.map(batch => \`<option value="${batch.id}">${batch.batch}</option>\`).join("")`

Comment: hey, I hope you can help me, to assemble the object, I already know the active contract and which batch I should display first, as well as the invoices for the batch,

but if I change the batch, I want to display invoices for the selected batch.

You can help me with this.

Initially, I show invoices with filter
`let contractInAttendance = 1;
let batchFilteredByContractId = contract.batchs.filter (batch => batch.id === contractInAttendance);

// do something with return`

Comment: I updated the code, so understand better!

Another thing, if possible, click on the contract and start displaying the data of the selected contract